# Memory issue with image zooming in java

Tags: java, swing, memory, garbage-collection, jvm

**Env:**

JDK: 1.8u112 oracle

JRE: 10.0.2

JVM max heap size: ~2GB.

OS: Windows 10

IDE: Netbeans 8.1

RAM: DDR4 8GB

Processor: 6700hq i7 intel

**Context**

A simple GUI that opens an image file (jpg/png) and magnifies it via user input.

**Desc**

A class extends JFrame. The frame's contentPane has a JButton,a JLabel & a JScrollPane. Clicking the button shows a JFileChooser. The label is inside the scrollpane. Selecting a file opens it in the label(open image files only for the purposes of this question-jpg/png tested upon). The label has a mouse wheel listener that causes zooming of image via `Image.getScaledInstance`. At each zoom, magnifiaction (ratio of new image width(or height) to corresponding original's) and `Runtime.totalMemory` is printed.

**Problem**

1. Upon zooming into the image, too much memory seems to being consumed by the code. The task manager shows 1708 MB memory usage at 11.8 times magnification for a 7.23KB png image. Expected should be around the order of 11.8*11.8*7.23KB
2. Upon zooming out, the memory consumption doesn't reduce
3. Why is the heap expanding so much(at around ~17 times mag, it reaches 2GB) in the first place? Are discarded `ImageIcon` objects(see code) not being gced?
4. How to make code viable for mag where mag * mag * originalImageSize(in bytes)<50% JVM max heap size?

**Code**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Image image;
Dimension size;
private double mag = 1;
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

public gui() {
    initComponents();

}

private void zoom() {

    int[] newSize = {(int) (size.width * mag), (int) (size.height * mag)};

    if (newSize[0] > 0 && newSize[1] > 0) {
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(newSize[0], newSize[1], Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
    }

    System.out.println("mag:" + (int) (mag * 100) + "% mem:" + runtime.totalMemory() / 1024 / 1024 + "MB");

}

private void loadImage(File imgFile) throws IOException {

    String path = imgFile.getPath().toLowerCase();
    if (path.endsWith("gif")) {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(path);

        image = icon.getImage();

        label.setIcon(icon);

    } else {
        image = ImageIO.read(imgFile);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        label.setIcon(icon);
    }

    size = new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    dialog = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    button = new javax.swing.JButton();

    dialog.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("D:\\"));
        dialog.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                dialogActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Image Viewer");

        label.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP);
        label.addMouseWheelListener(new java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener() {
            public void mouseWheelMoved(java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent evt) {
                labelMouseWheelMoved(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(label);

        button.setText("open");
        button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                buttonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 689, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(button)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(button)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 430, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

private void dialogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if (evt.getActionCommand().equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {

        try {
            File file = dialog.getSelectedFile();

            loadImage(file);

            setTitle(file.getPath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}                                      

private void labelMouseWheelMoved(java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent evt) {                                      

    if (image != null) {
        int amt = -evt.getWheelRotation();
        double newMag = mag + amt * 0.1;

        if (newMag > 0) {
            mag = newMag;
            zoom();

        }

    }


}                                     

private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    dialog.showOpenDialog(this);
}                                      

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            new gui().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton button;
private javax.swing.JFileChooser dialog;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JLabel label;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Test file**

Any jpg or png image should do besides [test file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COw7G.png).

**Output from the test file**

mag:110% mem:123MB
mag:120% mem:123MB
mag:130% mem:123MB
mag:140% mem:123MB
mag:150% mem:123MB
mag:160% mem:123MB
mag:150% mem:123MB
mag:160% mem:123MB
mag:170% mem:123MB
mag:180% mem:155MB
mag:190% mem:155MB
mag:200% mem:155MB
mag:210% mem:155MB
mag:220% mem:155MB
mag:230% mem:157MB
mag:240% mem:157MB
mag:250% mem:157MB
mag:260% mem:157MB
mag:270% mem:253MB
mag:280% mem:253MB
mag:290% mem:253MB
mag:300% mem:253MB
mag:310% mem:253MB
mag:320% mem:256MB
mag:330% mem:256MB
mag:340% mem:256MB
mag:350% mem:256MB
mag:360% mem:256MB
mag:370% mem:393MB
mag:380% mem:393MB
mag:390% mem:393MB
mag:400% mem:393MB
mag:410% mem:393MB
mag:420% mem:393MB
mag:430% mem:466MB
mag:440% mem:466MB
mag:450% mem:466MB
mag:460% mem:466MB
mag:470% mem:466MB
mag:480% mem:466MB
mag:489% mem:541MB
mag:499% mem:541MB
mag:509% mem:541MB
mag:519% mem:541MB
mag:529% mem:541MB
mag:539% mem:641MB
mag:549% mem:641MB
mag:559% mem:641MB
mag:569% mem:641MB
mag:579% mem:641MB
mag:589% mem:825MB
mag:599% mem:825MB
mag:609% mem:825MB
mag:619% mem:825MB
mag:609% mem:825MB
mag:619% mem:825MB
mag:629% mem:892MB
mag:639% mem:892MB
mag:649% mem:892MB
mag:659% mem:892MB
mag:669% mem:892MB
mag:679% mem:892MB
mag:689% mem:881MB
mag:699% mem:881MB
mag:709% mem:881MB
mag:719% mem:881MB
mag:729% mem:1029MB
mag:739% mem:1029MB
mag:749% mem:1029MB
mag:759% mem:1029MB
mag:769% mem:1104MB
mag:779% mem:1104MB
mag:789% mem:1104MB
mag:799% mem:1104MB
mag:809% mem:1075MB
mag:819% mem:1075MB
mag:829% mem:1075MB
mag:839% mem:1182MB
mag:849% mem:1182MB
mag:859% mem:1182MB
mag:869% mem:1289MB
mag:879% mem:1289MB
mag:889% mem:1542MB
mag:899% mem:1542MB
mag:909% mem:1542MB
mag:919% mem:1569MB
mag:929% mem:1569MB
mag:939% mem:1569MB
mag:949% mem:1480MB
mag:959% mem:1480MB
mag:969% mem:1548MB
mag:979% mem:1548MB
mag:989% mem:1655MB
mag:999% mem:1655MB
mag:1009% mem:1707MB
mag:1019% mem:1707MB
mag:1029% mem:1802MB
mag:1039% mem:1850MB
mag:1049% mem:1850MB
mag:1059% mem:1871MB
mag:1069% mem:1871MB
mag:1079% mem:1801MB
mag:1089% mem:1862MB
mag:1099% mem:1862MB
mag:1109% mem:1815MB
mag:1119% mem:1822MB
mag:1129% mem:1758MB
mag:1139% mem:1774MB
mag:1149% mem:1711MB
mag:1159% mem:1734MB
mag:1169% mem:1676MB
**mag:1179% mem:1708MB**
mag:1189% mem:1654MB

Comment: `totalMemory()` memory is, as the name suggests, the *total* memory, not the memory in use. If you want to know, how much memory is in use, subtract the `freeMemory​()` from the total memory.

Comment: @Holger but why is even the total memory increasing? And why so much compared to the magnified img's size? For eg. Xmx 1gb should be more than enough to run this at 18.9 times magnification (magnified image size a measly 2.3Mb) but it crashes precisely because of the need for totalMemory to go above 1gb.(at the time of crash free memory for example case was 327Mb)

Comment: It is not increasing; the last number is smaller than the one you have marked bold. Likewise, the numbers before it go up and down, there is no tendency to increase. The reason why it doesn’t behave as if you’ve specified `-Xmx1G` is quiet simple: you didn’t specify `-Xmx1G`.

Answer (score 0):

> Are discarded ImageIcon objects(see code) not being gced?

How they could be GC'ed without the GC running?

Why should the GC run when the memory suffices?

That's it. The GC runs when needed and there isn't much to win by keeping the memory usage lower than necessary.

For efficiency reasons, the GC is actually a "survivor collector": It only deals with surviving objects and what's left behind is free memory. Therefore it makes sense to run it ALAP as most objects die young.

---

> Expected should be around the order of 11.8*11.8*7.23KB

No, a Java process is free to use all the memory you gave it.

> Upon zooming out, the memory consumption doesn't reduce

Yes, as there's no need for the GC to run.

> Why is the heap expanding so much(at around ~17 times mag, it reaches 2GB)

The images at all intermediate sizes are unreachable, but not yet collected.

> How to make code viable for mag where mag * mag * originalImageSize(in bytes)<50% JVM max heap size?

You can't. When the memory will be needed by the Java process, then it gets reclaimed.

---

I was lying a bit. You can call `System.gc` manually and it'll probably help. But don't do it. While this answers the last question, it solves no real problem. If you want to keep the memory usage low, then give Java less memory using `-Xmx1000M` or alike.